# [which... == column contains letter

Tags: r

Similar to `[ which(Data$Year=='2013'), ]`, I would like to check if column `Code` contains a specific letter.

How to change the syntax correctly?

`[ which(Data$Code=='A'), ]` didn't work because there are more letters than A in the column.

Comment: Is this `R`? Please add the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` or `grepl` in this case. You have several options:

**Retrieve indices of Data$Code that contain the letter "A":**

```
grep("A", Data$Code)
```

**Check if the Data$Code contains any "A"s:**

```
any(grep("A", Data$Code))
```

**Create a logical vector that states for each element if it contains the letter "A"**

```
grepl("A", Data$Code)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the code I was looking for. Is there are also a command to negate? Code contains a specific letter NOT.

Comment: Yep, just put a `!` at the beginning